# Calling LinearRegression.fit() causes program to fail no matter which column I try to use

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to train on a set of data but no matter what column I choose (or even when I create a nonexisting column) I get errors:

```
        1) u'Field "prediction_1" does not exist.\nAvailable fields: features, prediction'

        2) u'requirement failed: Column prediction already exists.
```

The code currently looks like this:

```
    dt = LinearRegression(featuresCol="features", labelCol="prediction", maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)

    predictions = crossval.fit(trainingData).transform(trainingData)
    bins = predictions.select("prediction").distinct().collect()
    for row in bins:
        rows = predictions.select(["features", "prediction"]).filter(predictions.prediction == row.prediction)
        dt_model = dt.fit(rows)
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Try changing the name of your label column to something else and see if it works.

Comment: @Shaido that's what produced the two separate errors. If I change it to a non existing column I get error 1. If it exists then I get error 2.

Comment: You need to actually rename the column in the dataframe as well. The first error indicates you only changed the column name when calling `LinearRegression`. Use `withColumnRenamed`.

Comment: It could be `crossval` that is the reason for the error as well. Which line is the reason for the failure? What is the definition of `crossval`?

Comment: @Shaido your solution was perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help :)